# 110 Connection timed out - using play 2.1.3 and nginx

Tags: nginx, playframework-2.1, proxypass

Nginx returns a 110 connection timed out

nginx error log

```
2013/08/14 01:06:25 [error] 29031#0: *19429255 connect() failed (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: ***.***.***.***, server: d.localhost.com, request: "GET /dashboard/d HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://0.0.0.0:9000/dashboard/d", host: "d.localhost.com", referrer: "http://d.localhost.com/"
```

I served assets file with nginx and reduceded load on play but still i get this error 
have tried increasing the 
proxy_connect_timeout , send_timeout , proxy_read_timeout but the error persists 
even when the servers load is low it throws up these errors

this happens regularly with different requests

and my nginx configuration is

```
upstream dWeb {
server 0.0.0.0:9000; 
}
server {
listen 80;
client_max_body_size 50M;
server_name  d.localhost.com;
root /home/web/d-web;
send_timeout 20;
location /
{
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_connect_timeout 10000;
    send_timeout 10000;
    proxy_read_timeout 10000;
    keepalive_timeout 10000;
    root /home/web/dsp-web/d-web-0.1.0;
    autoindex on;
    proxy_pass http://dWeb;
    error_log /data/nginxlog/d.rd/error.log;
}
}
```

Comment: you have an upstream named dWeb right ! can you paste that too

Comment: upstream dspWeb {
       server 0.0.0.0:9000;
    }

Comment: Should that be 127.0.0.1:9000 or localhost:9000? You can try access localhost:9000 to find whether it can be accessed correctly.

Comment: @TroyCheng the proxy_pass is working fine at normal load when the number of requests increases I get the 110 time out for certain requests so the problem is not with 0.0.0.0:9000;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the actual problem was play was not able to handle all the requests that where sent to it and the connection timed out eventually

like increasing workers in nginx in play we have to increase thread pools to improve parallel performance

overriding the default thread pool to increase performance

**default configuration**

```
play {
  akka {
    event-handlers = ["akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger","akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
    loglevel = WARNING
    actor {
      default-dispatcher = {
        fork-join-executor {
          parallelism-factor = 1.0
          parallelism-max = 24
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the parallelism-factor is number of threads to be created per available core
increasing it to 4
since there is a lot of read and write operations per request

**overridden configuration**
    parallelism-factor = 4.0
    parallelism-max = 24

this stopped the 110 time out error